# Quantifier for an implication

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am teaching someone about statements, the very basis of mathematical thinking, but now I am a bit confused myself. For

$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x > 2 \Rightarrow x > 3 $

to be a statement, does it need the $ \in \mathbb{R} $ part? And the quantifier?

So is $ x > 2 \Rightarrow x > 3 $ a statement or not?

Comment: I think $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $x > 2 \implies x > 3$ is a shorthand for $\forall x$ $(x \in \mathbb{R} \wedge x > 2) \implies x > 3$. But I am not familiar with mathematical logic.

Comment: This is incorrect, see Clive Newstead's answer.

Comment: Alex Vong, Can you be more specific about what is incorrect?

Comment: @AlexVong: It's less incorrect than you might think, since in general $(p \wedge q) \Rightarrow r$ is equivalent to $p \Rightarrow (q \Rightarrow r)$, so what you write is equivalent to the thing it's shorthand for. (The statement itself is false, though.)

Comment: @AlexVong: As Clive stated, "If A, then ( if B, then C )." asserts C if two conditions both hold, and hence it is equivalent to what "If A and B, then C." asserts. Makes sense?

Comment: @user21820 Yes, I get it now. An alternative way to see it would be that both $(p \wedge q) \implies r$ and $p \implies (q \implies r)$ expands to $\neg p \vee \neg q \vee r$.

Comment: @AlexVong: Correct. Though note that the equivalence "$A ⇒ B \equiv \neg A \lor B$" is only valid for classical logic, but that's what you should focus on for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's understood that the variable $x$ refers to a real number, then it can be omitted; otherwise, it cannot.

This practice is known as *bounded quantification*. In general, when you write $\forall x$, the variable $x$ is taken to range over the entire universe of discourse, whatever that may be. If the universe of discourse is not specified, then it is typically understood by context (e.g. the [von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) in set theory).

If $p(x)$ is some statement with a free variable $x$, then the expression $\forall x \in X,\, p(x)$ is shorthand for $\forall x,\, (x \in X \Rightarrow p(x))$. It then doesn't matter what the universe of discourse is, because in order for the hypothesis $x \in X$ to be specified, you've instantly restricted yourself to elements of $X$.

Thus the statement $\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\, x > 2 \Rightarrow x > 3$ is shorthand for
$$\forall x,\, (x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow (x > 2 \Rightarrow x > 3))$$
If it were understood from context that the variable $x$ refers to a real number, then you could omit the "$\in \mathbb{R}$" part so that the statement becomes $\forall x,\, (x > 2 \Rightarrow x > 3)$; in fact, in this case, you could shorten this even further to become just $\forall x > 2,\, x > 3$.

Comment: Thanks! So the quantifier is not optional?

Comment: You need the quantifier, otherwise the expression has a free variable and so cannot be assigned a truth value.

Comment: In addition, $\exists x\in X, p(x)$ is commonly the shorthand for $\exists x\left(x\in X \land p(x)\right)$.
Note that upon negating $\exists$ and $\forall$ generally switch roles, but the shorthand form remains, but switches its meaning:
$\lnot\left(\exists x\left(x\in X \land p(x)\right)\right) = \lnot\left(\exists x\in X, p(x)\right) \equiv \forall x\in X, \lnot p(x) = \forall x\left(x\in X \rightarrow \lnot p(x)\right)$.

Comment: There is a very very slight problem with your claimed short-hand of "$∀x,(x∈R⇒(x>2⇒x>3))$", because at least in standard first-order logic the constituents of a compound proposition are to be interpreted separately. So "$x>2$" must make sense for every object $x$, which is not the case since "$<$" is only defined for real numbers. You could argue that "$<$" is just a relation on **all** objects that happens to be a set of pairs of reals. But what about more complex things like "$\forall f : S \to S\ ( \exists x \in S\ ( f(x) = x ) )$"?

Comment: @user21820: In ZFC with first-order logic, $x>2$ can be written entirely in terms of the predicate $\in$ and the usual logical connectives, so it makes sense regardless of what kind of object $x$ is. (Indeed, under ZFC, there is only one kind of object, namely sets.) It only has useful meaning when $x$ refers to a real number, but that's not the point :P For the same reason, you can write "$\pi$ is an abelian group of order $5$" as a first-order sentence in ZFC.

Comment: @user21820 If you want to formulate it in first-order logic, your predicates are [per definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_structures) subsets of $D^n$ where $n$ is the arity and $D$ your universe. One could take $\in R$ as a unary predicate or alternatively $\in$ as a binary predicate and $R$ as a constant. In the latter case, the universe has to contain $R$ itself.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: Yes haha I'm just picking a tiny nitpick with the way first-order formalization does not match completely with our intuitive reasoning, in which the restricted quantifier is in fact more than just a short-hand but also restricts the type of the object quantified over, so that the inner sentence becomes syntactically correct. This mismatch is especially obvious when dealing with functions with the "$f(x)$" syntax.

Comment: @user21820: Sure, and I agree. These issues magically disappear when working within type theory, rather than set theory+FOL... unfortunately type theory has its own shortcomings.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: Yea. Unfortunately. For one, a lot of type theories don't support sub-typing, so it's meaningless to even ask whether an object belongs to another type or not.

Answer (score 8):

> the very basis of mathematical thinking

is about communication as much as it is about formal statements.

Whether or not there's ambiguity in your example depends on the context. If it's part of a discussion about the real numbers you don't need the extra specificity. If it's a standalone example about quantifiers, you do.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't specify it, there is a possibility of ambiguity. For example, consider the example
$\forall x, x>3 \Rightarrow x>2$. 
If $x$ is real, it's obviously true. If however we take it over the lattice of divisibility, $x=9$ contradicts the statement, as $9$ is an odd number.

Comment: Nice counterexample, for a statement that, at first sight, seems to be universally true!

Comment: Note that the OP's example is in fact a false statement (which is OK since the question is about formulating a statement). You quite naturally reversed it.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, I did it deliberately, but I hope you understand the purpose

Answer (score 3):

Better to specify $\forall x \in \mathbb R$, because it could be possibly that your statement is about $\forall x \in \mathbb Q$, or $\forall x \in \mathbb Z$, etc.

Comment: To down-voter: please leave reason why you down-voted, any suggestion for edit to improve. Is it something fundamentally wrong, or are there minor issues that could be fixed/corrected?For soft question like this, I'm not expecting a down-vote without any reason/suggestion.

Comment: Also, this is the first post to the question, so if you down-vote because you think it mimic/simplifies other answers, you are wrong.